# Print invoice button gives blank page with error

Tags: php, magento

I want to print the invoice through the back-end of magento at invoices but it gives me this error after I turned on the errors in `index.php`

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getPdf() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Sales/Invoice.php on line 119

```
public function printAction()
{
    if ($invoiceId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id')) {
        if ($invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($invoiceId)) {
            $pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($invoice));
            $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').
                '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->_forward('noRoute');
    }
}
```

The error says that this line:

```
$pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($invoice));
```

contains an error but I don't see any problem also I don't get it why it gives error on a core folder php file. I haven't modify it in any way too.

Answer (score 0):

First, tell which version of Magento you are using?

Meanwhile, you may try the following:

- disable all the installed extensions, and when enabling them one by one, figure out which module is triggering the issue;
- clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses old Zend PDF library which has an issue:

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12093

Just comment

```
//abstract public function __construct();
//abstract public function __destruct();
```

in

*app\code\local\Zend\Pdf\FileParserDataSource.php.*